# PhoneGap remote build ios gives [Error: ENOENT]

Tags: cordova, web-applications, phonegap-build

Just want to upload my project to phonegap build(build.phonegap.com), and when I run this command in myproject folder:

```
phonegap remote build ios
```

It gives an error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/myname/Sites/myproject/www/config.xml']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/myname/Sites/myproject/www/config.xml' }
    [error] ENOENT, open '/Users/myname/Sites/myproject/www/config.xml'
```

Which means the path to config.xml file is incorrect I guess, but I double checked it, the config.xml file is in the right path. Can anyone help me with this please? How do I sorted it out?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error trying 
phonegap remote build android

~/code/phonegap/hello2$ phonegap remote build android
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/home/pes/code/phonegap/hello2/www/config.xml']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/pes/code/phonegap/hello2/www/config.xml' }
   [error] ENOENT, open '/home/pes/code/phonegap/hello2/www/config.xml'

the sollution was to go into the projects www dircetory and link to config.xml with
$ ln -s ../config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the config.xml file in the www folder.
Worked for me.